# Doctrine sets valid parameters to null on flush()

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two many-to-one relationships, where objects `$countryFrom` and `$countryTo` from `Notification` get the values from column `id_country_form` and `id_country_to` and looks in `Country` table for an `id` with the same value. **I have setters and getters for all the properties.**

**Entity Notification**

```
class Notification
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_country_from", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $countryFrom;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_country_to", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $countryTo;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_country_from", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $idCountryFrom;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_country_to", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $idCountryTo;   
}
```

**Entity Country**

```
class Country
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;  
}
```

However, when I want to insert data in DB from the controller, the properties associated with `id_country_form` and `id_country_to`are setted to null.

**Controller Method**

```
$notif = new Notification;
$notif->setCountryFrom(5); // SET to NULL 
$notif->setCountryTo(6); // SET to NULL       
$notif->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());

$em->persist($notif);
$em->flush();
```

**var_dump($notification) after persist()**

```
object(AppBundle\Entity\Notification)[457]
private 'countryFrom' => null
private 'countryTo' => null
private 'idCountryFrom' => int 5 // SET
private 'idCountryTo' => int 6   // SET    
private 'createdAt' => 
  object(DateTime)[448]
     public 'date' => string '2016-06-14 06:32:35.000000' (length=26)
     public 'timezone_type' => int 3
     public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
private 'id' => null
```

Here we see that idCurrencyFrom and idCurrencyTo are setted after persist(), but the next error occurs:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO alerts (id_currency_from, id_currency_to, active, created_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, "2016-06-14 06:32:35"]:
```

The code worked before I set the many-to-one relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I can't assume without looking your setter methods but you should pass entity to setter method not id. For example;

```
 $country = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Country')->find(5);
 $notif->setCountry($country);
```

Comment: Did you look at the `var_dump` result? The values are stored properly, the problem is when I call flush(), I don't know what Doctrine does, but it overrides the values to `null`.

Comment: You are setting $idCountryFrom property not $countryFrom property so and in your entity, you define 2 property for 1 column you should remove $idCountryFrom and $idCountryTo.